# Series expansions and algebraic branch points

Tags: series-expansion

I have the expression

$$(1-x^4)^{-1/4}$$

where $0<x<1$, which gives me a real number. When I try to expand it around $x=1$, Mathematica gives me complex coefficients, which makes me think that he is picking some particular (and unwanted) branch.

```
$Assumptions = And[0 < x < 1];

Series[(1 - x^4)^(-1/4), {x, 1, 0}] // Simplify // Normal

(*(1/2-\[ImaginaryI]/2)/(-1+x)^(1/4)*)
```

The lowest order coefficient is

$$\frac{1-i}{2(x-1)^{1/4}}$$

which is complex (the numerator has a complex phase of $-\pi/4$ and the denominator of $\pi/4$, giving the coefficient a total phase of $-\pi/2$).

If instead I previously perform a change of variable $t=(1-x)^{1/4}$, which removes the multivalued behavior at the singularity, Mathematica will give me a real coefficient (as expected):

```
Normal[Series[1/(1 - x^4)^(1/4) /. x -> 1 - t^4, {t, 0, 0}]] /.t -> (1 - x)^(1/4)
```

The result is

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}(1-x)^{1/4}}$$

It is not economical for me perform constantly changes of variables like that, so I want to know if there is a way to control the output in cases like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The challenge is that `Series[f[x], {x, 1, n}]` creates an expansion in terms of `x - 1`.  Since `(1 - x^4)^(-1/4)` is complex for `x > 1`, so are the expansion coefficients.  If `Series` did its expansion for `0 < x < 1`, as given in `$Assumptions`, in terms of `1 - x`, real coefficients would result instead.  A comment by [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) in [Question 112291](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/112291/1063) suggests how this might be accomplished.  For generality, define

```
mySeries[f_, lst_] := 
    Quiet@Module[{z = First@lst, lst1 = ReplacePart[lst, 2 -> -(lst[[2]])]}, 
    (Series[f /. z -> -z, lst1] // Normal) /. z -> -z]
```

Then, for the expression in the question,

```
mySeries[(1 - x^4)^(-1/4), {x, 1, 2}]
(* 1/(Sqrt[2] (1 - x)^(1/4)) + (3 (1 - x)^(3/4))/(8 Sqrt[2]) +
   (13 (1 - x)^(7/4))/(128 Sqrt[2]) *)
```

as desired.

Comment: Thank you, that was a very useful and elegant solution.